# Why is the url for the profile picture that's stored in firebase firestore become invalid when I change other inputs in my form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I'm trying to build a form that updates user settings. The user settings could be newly inserted from the page, or they could be updated.
Since the user can upload their own profile pictures, I had to upload image as a File to firebase storage, and make a download link that's stored in firestore along with other user information. e.g

```
age : "26",
gender : "Male",
name : "Issam Olwan",
philoType : "Pragmatic",
profilePictureURL : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b**********.com/o/profilePictures%2Fundefined?alt=media&token=8268f785-4e9c",
timestamp : 24 August 2023 at 15:21:22 UTC+3,
uid : "JY7NjOwYw1PRjZbwQTwfKXOWlPP2"
```

as you can see from the example document, the url for the profile picture has "undefined".

What im doing is when component first loads, the user's information is fetched and placed in the inputs including the profile picture.

```
"use client"

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth"
import { db, storage, auth } from "@/firebase/config"
import {
  collection,
  addDoc,
  orderBy,
  limit,
  query,
  where,
  getDocs,
  serverTimestamp,
  updateDoc,
  FieldValue,
} from "firebase/firestore"
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"
import { scrollToTop } from "@/utils/helpers"

type UserData = {
  uid: string
  name: string
  age: string
  gender: string
  philoType: string
  timestamp: FieldValue
  profilePictureURL?: string | undefined // Optional for profile picture URL
}
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState("")

  const router = useRouter()
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth)

 const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    profilePictureURL: "",
    age: "",
    gender: "",
    philoType: "",
  })
  const [profilePictureFile, setProfilePictureFile] = useState<File | null>(null)

useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      router.push("/login")
      return
    }

    const fetchLatestUserSettings = async () => {
      try {
        const usersCollection = collection(db, "users")
        const userQuery = query(
          usersCollection,
          where("uid", "==", user.uid),
          orderBy("timestamp", "desc"),
          limit(1)
        )
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(userQuery)

        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
          const userDoc = querySnapshot.docs[0].data()
          setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
            name: userDoc.name,
            age: userDoc.age,
            gender: userDoc.gender,
            philoType: userDoc.philoType,
            profilePictureURL: userDoc.profilePictureURL || prevFormData.profilePictureURL,
          }))
          // setProfilePictureFile(userDoc.profilePictureURL)
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error fetching user settings:", err)
        setTimeout(() => setError(err as string), 3000)
      }
      setError("")
    }

    fetchLatestUserSettings()
  }, [router, user])
```

But then there's the submission, which is causing the issue with the url for the picture becoming invalid

```
 const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    scrollToTop()
    setLoading(true)

    try {
      const usersCollection = collection(db, "users")
      const userQuery = query(usersCollection, where("uid", "==", user?.uid))
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(userQuery)

      // if a document already exists
      if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        const existingUserDoc = querySnapshot.docs[0]
        const existingUserData = existingUserDoc.data() as UserData

        let updateData: UserData = {
          uid: user?.uid as string,
          name: formData.name,
          age: formData.age,
          gender: formData.gender,
          philoType: formData.philoType,
          timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
          profilePictureURL: existingUserData.profilePictureURL,
        }

        if (profilePictureFile) {
          const storageRef = ref(storage, `profilePictures/${profilePictureFile.name}`)
          await uploadBytes(storageRef, profilePictureFile)
          const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef)
          updateData.profilePictureURL = downloadURL
        }

        // Check if any fields are different from existing data
        const fieldsChanged = Object.keys(updateData).some(
          (key) => updateData[key as keyof UserData] !== existingUserData[key as keyof UserData]
        )

        if (fieldsChanged) {
          await updateDoc(existingUserDoc.ref, updateData)
        }
      } else {
        // if no documents with those entries have been entered
        const newUserData: UserData = {
          uid: user?.uid as string,
          name: formData.name,
          age: formData.age,
          gender: formData.gender,
          philoType: formData.philoType,
          timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
        }

        if (profilePictureFile) {
          const storageRef = ref(storage, `profilePictures/${profilePictureFile.name}`)
          await uploadBytes(storageRef, profilePictureFile)
          const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef)
          newUserData.profilePictureURL = downloadURL
        }

        await addDoc(usersCollection, newUserData)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
      setError(err as string)
      setTimeout(() => setError(""), 3000)
    }

    setShowAlert(true)
    setLoading(false)
    setTimeout(() => router.push("/"), 3000)
  }
```

My question is why is this happening ? I'm not sure what im doing wrong.